# In Excel VBA Macro does ActiveWindow.Scroll change ActiveCell at all

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, microsoft-excel-2003, vba

I'm cleaning up and extending some excel VBA macros (written and currently running in Excel 2003), and I have a question about how far I can go in cleaning up without modifying the output.

There are sevral ActiveWindow.Scroll or similar entries in the macro. So far as I understand these only move the spreadsheet within the viewable window. Is this correct?

Just to expand and confirm: Removing Scroll entries should in no way affect the selected cell, row, or column the macro will be working upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct. These are typically just a side effect of recording a macro. You should be able to remove them without affecting your macro.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. In my experience I've not found a case where they've done anything meaningful, but it's good to have additional confirmation they indeed do not affect data processing portions of the macro.